# Make array jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to make an array like this. (on alert it gives object)

```
var playlist = [{"title":"Kalimba","mp3":"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3"}];
```

**From:**

```
var playlist = [];
$.ajax({
    url: 'url.php',
    data: {
        album_name: album_name
    },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function( data ) {
        var data_array = JSON.parse(data);
        for( var i=0; i<data_array.length; i++ ) {
            var value = data_array[i].split('::');
            playlist.push('{"title":"Kalimba","mp3":"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3"},'); // putting the same thing just for testing.
        }
        alert(playlist);
    }
});
```

Now the new array `playlist` didn't seem to be working for me. i guess there is something wrong the way i am creating an array like above.

Comment: `playlist.push({"title":"Kalimba","mp3":"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3"});`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to push object instead of object string:

```
playlist.push({"title":"Kalimba","mp3":"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3"});
//------------^---remove the single quote.
```

Comment: thanks alot working now. i will accept the answer in 10min.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```js
var playlist =[{"title":"Kalimba","mp3":"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3"}];

alert(JSON.stringify(playlist));
```

Answer (score 1):

- As @Jai said you need to push an object:    `playlist.push({"title":"Kalimba","mp3":"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3"});`
- Arrays in JavaScript are objects.
- You'd be better using    the console to log or debug your javascript.
- In this    [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aojvcxss/1/) you can see
  that the array    is created and the object pushed to it but its
  still logged as an    object.
- And since you are using jQuery it has a method [isArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isarray/) to determine if
  something is an array or not.

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) for making array.

```
playlist = $.map(data_array, function(val, i){
      splitArr = val.split('::')
      return {
        'title':splitArr[0],
        'mp3':splitArr[1]
      }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can try like this

```js
var playlist = [];
$.ajax({
    url: 'url.php',
    data: {
        album_name: album_name
    },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function( data ) {
        var data_array = JSON.parse(data);
        for( var i=0; i<data_array.length; i++ ) {
            var value = data_array[i].split('::');
            var ArrObj = '{"title":"Kalimba","mp3":"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3"},'; 
            playlist.push(ArrObj); 
        }
        alert(playlist);
    }
});
```